# I cannot print the IP addresses to a file using Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, input, file-io

I am copy - paste several IP addresses to a file and then I am trying to print them. Only I get the first IP address. I know that I need to tell the file to go to the second line and print the output again but I do not know how.

CODE:

```
file = open("MgmtIP.txt", "w")

file.writelines(input())

file.close()

print("\n \n \n ")


file = open("MgmtIP.txt", "r")

for index in file:

    print(index)

file.close()
```

======================
output on Pycharm:

10.10.20.1 ---> Input 4 IP Addresses

10.10.20.2

10.10.20.3

10.10.20.4

10.10.20.1   --> output only the First IP Address

Process finished with exit code 0

=====================================

Note:
I want to get each IP Address and ssh to each device and get some outputs.

Thank you all.

Comment: How are you inputting 4 IPs on 4 separate lines with only one `input()` prompt?

Comment: Did the given solution not work?

Answer (score 1):

As you've written `writefiles(input())`, it takes only the first value you input and press enter. The remaining values aren't registered by `input()`.
You can use something like

```
addresses = input().split()
for line in addresses:
    file.writeline(line)
file.close()
```

This will work if all addresses are entered in one line and are space separated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You need to read all the data from the file then print.

```
with open("MgmtIP.txt", 'w') as file1:
    file1.writelines(input().split())

with open("MgmtIP.txt", 'r') as file2:
    data = file2.readlines()
    for ip in data:
        print(ip)
```

Comment: The data appears to be input in separate lines, not same line separated with spaces